# Every time I upload .sql database to phpmyadmin I get this error?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, hosting

I'm really not sure what to do or how to solve it??[image: Picture of error- please help]

```
    <div class="error"><h1>Error</h1>
<p><strong>SQL query:</strong>
<a href="tbl_sql.php?sql_query=SHOW+TABLE+STATUS+FROM+%60carinage_wp7%60+LIKE+%27wp_comments%27&amp;show_query=1&amp;db=carinage_wp7&amp;table=wp_comments&amp;token=65265621290abccbc6da4cd0bf7dcd20"><span class="nowrap"><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Edit" alt="Edit" class="icon ic_b_edit" /> Edit</span></a>    </p>
<p>
<span class="syntax"><span class="inner_sql"><a href="./url.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.mysql.com%2Fdoc%2Frefman%2F5.5%2Fen%2Fshow.html&amp;token=65265621290abccbc6da4cd0bf7dcd20" target="mysql_doc"><span class="syntax_alpha syntax_alpha_reservedWord">SHOW</span></a>  <span class="syntax_alpha syntax_alpha_reservedWord">TABLE</span>  <span class="syntax_alpha syntax_alpha_reservedWord">STATUS</span>  <span class="syntax_alpha syntax_alpha_reservedWord">FROM</span>  <span class="syntax_quote syntax_quote_backtick">`carinage_wp7`</span>  <a href="./url.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.mysql.com%2Fdoc%2Frefman%2F5.5%2Fen%2Fstring-comparison-functions.html%23operator_like&amp;token=65265621290abccbc6da4cd0bf7dcd20" target="mysql_doc"><span class="syntax_alpha syntax_alpha_reservedWord">LIKE</span></a>  <span class="syntax_quote syntax_quote_single">'wp_comments'</span></span></span>
</p>
<p>
    <strong>MySQL said: </strong><a href="./url.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.mysql.com%2Fdoc%2Frefman%2F5.5%2Fen%2Ferror-messages-server.html&amp;token=65265621290abccbc6da4cd0bf7dcd20" target="mysql_doc"><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Documentation" alt="Documentation" class="icon ic_b_help" /></a>
</p>
<code>
#2006 - MySQL server has gone away
```

Comment: Looks like there is a syntax error in your file. Can you show it to us?

Comment: I've just added the error bit!! thanks

Comment: I mean show us your .sql file (or at least the first few lines). The file looks suspicious and contains a SHOW TABLE STATUS statement. How was this .sql file produced?